Seeking Efficient Solutions for Handling Asynchronous File Operations in Node.js
I'm currently developing a Node.js application that requires managing a high volume of asynchronous file operations like reading, writing, and deleting. As I scale up these operations, I'm running into performance bottlenecks and occasional errors such as EMFILE (too many open files).
Current Approach:
I'm utilizing asynchronous methods from the fs module like fs.readFile and fs.writeFile.
I've created a simple queue mechanism using async.queue to control the concurrency of file operations.
Despite the queue, the response times fluctuate, and I feel the overall throughput could be improved. I occasionally face EMFILE errors during peak server load.
Experimented with graceful-fs as an alternative to the standard fs module, but it didn’t lead to a significant improvement.
const async = require('async');

const fileQueue = async.queue((task, callback) => {
    fs.readFile(task.filePath, (err, data) => {
        if (err) return callback(err);
        // business logic for filtration in file you can just add map loop or filter loop here
        callback();
    });
}, 5);

fileQueue.drain = function() {
    console.log('All file operations have been processed.');
};

fileQueue.push({filePath: '/social-directory/file.txt'});


The answer below is likely correct, however if you are doing this in a distributed context consider https://www.npmjs.com/package/websemaphore [plug]
